# Windows hibernates after sleeping a while

Tags: windows

I frequently make my Windows 7 laptop sleep. However, recently, after it's slept a few hours, it spontaneously hibernates. I know that this is not because of battery because it still had 85% left after it resumed.

I am not sure what information to provide, so if you asked me in the comments, that would be great.

Comment: You can probably find a solution by going to start > control panel > power options and looking for settings regarding hibernation.

Answer (score 1):

Go to
`Start`-> `Control Panel`-> `Power Options`-> click `Advanced Power Plan Settings` on your power plan.
Now open `Sleep` -> set `Allow hybrid sleep` to Off -> set `Hibernate After` to 0 (Never).

**OR** just open Command Prompt as administrator (right click-> Run as administrator) and type there:

```
powercfg -h off
```

It will turn off hibernation forcefully.

Answer (score 0):

Some recent intel motherboards have this as an add on feature in the bios called "Intel rapid start technology".  You should be able to configure it in your bios settings.